# Send a transaction from Zero Address

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am writing and testing a smart contract. Using web3, I could not send a transaction from a **Zero Address** (0x0). I was wondering if it is ever possible to sign and send a transaction using the zero address. In effect the `msg.sender` in the function should be the zero address.

In other words, can this require statement any time return `true` ?

```
require(msg.sender == address(0))
```

From what I understand:

1. A contract A cannot call another contract B's function using a zero address. The `msg.sender` in contract B's function will always be contract A's sender.
2. It is not possible to generate a zero address as one of the addresses in an ethereum wallet. It will also be impossible to figure out the private key associated with the zero address.

Is there something wrong with my understandings or something that I am missing ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *I was wondering if it is ever possible to sign and send a transaction using the zero address.*

Only if you hold the private key controlling the zero address. Which is currently probably unknown, maybe even non-existing. As you can see, there are currently [no sent transactions](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000?fromaddress=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) from this address.

> *`require(msg.sender == address(0))`*

This statement has about the same value as checking `require(block.timestamp == 0)`. Which, if the EVM works correctly, will never happen.

I can't speak for the author's intentions - maybe they confused `msg.sender` with the fact that it's common practice to emit the `Transfer()` event with the first argument having the `0x0` address (usually used for minting tokens, which looks like if they were sent from the `0x0` address).

---

Note: Until 2017, it was possible to send a specifically signed transaction (without the correct private key) that resulted in the `msg.sender` having the **null sender** address `0xFFfFfFffFFfffFFfFFfFFFFFffFFFffffFfFFFfF`. This was fixed in the [EIP-86](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-86.md#specification), you can find more details in [this article](https://medium.com/@pirapira/impressions-on-metropolis-fe64251b4175).

Comment: hmm! 33 million dollars as of now, it is worth building a quantum computer and run a scanner to find out if such private key (for address(0)) exists